# Can the IE10 - F12 tools be used to degub JavaScript that is added dynamically?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10

I'm not that familiar with IE-10 and I'm trying to troubleshoot some code using the F12 tools.  I can't find a way to debug ( i.e. set break points, etc. ) in a script that is Ajaxed in, and then append to the DOM.

I can download it more conventionally using `<script>` but not changing things would be a bit easier.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of would be the temporarily add a `debugger;` command at the top of the dynamically added script file.  That will cause it to drop into the debugger as soon as that script starts to execute.  Once it drops into the debugger, you can set breakpoints in the now-loaded script that hasn't yet executed.

Comment: "use strict" has to be the first statement of the function. The debugger statement can be on any line. So you should move it after "use strict";